# Sticky nav with click to scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have run into a problem with my one page website.

I have made a sticky nav that gets a background when you start scrolling and i´m combining that with a click to scroll function. So if you click on about in the nav menu, it goes to that section on the page. I have used id links to do this.

My problem is that i can´t figure out how to adjust the position of this.

I want it to have a margin as the same size of the sticky nav.  Any input on how to fix this?

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#Produktet {
 padding-bottom: 200px;
}

html, body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.4em;
    word-spacing: 0.8%;
    letter-spacing: 0.4%;
 font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 1.8em;
    word-spacing: 0.4%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 3,5%;
    letter-spacing: 0.4%;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-bottom: 4%;
}

h2:after {
    display: block;
    height: 0.4%;
    background-color: #FFD700;
    content: " ";
    width: 10%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

header {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("img/citera hjemmeside baggrund (mindre).png");
 background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.logo {
    height: 110px;
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1%;
 margin-left: 3%;
}

.logo2 {
 width: 200px;
 
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 2%;
}

.logo3 {
 width: 200px;
 height: auto;
 padding-top: 2%;
}

.hero-text-box h3 {
 color: white;
 margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.hero-text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-text-box h1, h3{
 position: relative;
 animation: heading;
 animation-duration: 3s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes heading{
 0%{top: -500px}
 100%{top: 15px}
}

.top-box h2 {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.showcase {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20%, 1fr));
}

.showcase img {
 width: 300%;
 height: 100%;
}

.showcase-left img {
 margin-top: 5%;
}

.showcase-right {
 margin-top: -5%;
 margin-bottom: 20%;
 margin-right: 15%;
}

.showcase-right p {
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 10%;
}

.showcase-right h2 {
 margin-top: 30%;
 margin-right: 10%
}

.showcase-right h2 {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.box-me{
background-color: #E0E0E0;
padding: 40px;
}


/* ----- BUTTONS ----- */
.btn:link,
.btn:visited,
input[type=submit] {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1% 3%;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
    transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited,
input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #FFD700;
    border: 1px solid #FFD700;
    color: #000000;
    margin-right: 3%;
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
    border: 1px solid #FFD700;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active,
input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=submit]:active {
    background-color: #FFD700;
}

.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active {
    border: 1px solid #FFD700;
}

.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
    border: 1px solid #FFD700;
    color: #000;
}

.btn{
 opacity: 0;
 animation-name: btn;
 animation-duration: 3s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 
 transition-property: transform;
 transition-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes btn{
 0% {opacity: 0}
 100%{opacity: 1}
}

/* Main navi */
.main-nav {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 1.5%;
 margin-right: 10%;
 transition: background-color 200ms linear;
 padding-right: 4%;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
 padding-top: 2%;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 8px 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 90%;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFD700; 
}

/*__________________________*/

.long-copy {
    line-height: 145%;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
 margin-top: 0.5%;
}

.container {
 display: grid;
 grid-gap: 2%;
 text-align: center;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
 padding: 60px;
}

.container2 {
 display: grid;
 text-align: center;
 grid-gap: 6%;
 grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
 padding-bottom: 60px;
 background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

.center_text {
 display: grid;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #E0E0E0;
 padding-top: 3%;
}

.center_text h2 {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.fas {
 color: #FFD700;
 margin-bottom: 8%;
}

.case1 h2 {
 margin-top: 10%;
 font-size: 200%;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-left: -35%;
}

.case1 p {
 text-align: left;
 margin-top: 10%;
}

.find {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns:  repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-right: 10%;
}

.case2 img { 
 margin-top: 30%;
 margin-bottom: 10%;
 border-radius: 25px;
 width: 400px;
}

/*FOOTER*/
footer {
 background-color: #000;
 font-size: 80%;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 40px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}
 
#facebook {
 padding-left: 0.5%;
 color: #3B5998;
}

/*Sticky navbar*/

/* Page content */
.content {
padding: 16px;
}

/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */
.sticky {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}

/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */
.sticky + .content {
padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Sets the backgound color of the navbar */
.nav-color {
 background: #40717f;
 opacity: 0.9;
}

/* Big tablet to 1200px (widths smaller than the 1140px row) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .hero-text-box {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0 4%;
    }
    
    .row { padding: 0 2%; }
}


/* Small tablet to big tablet: from 768px to 1023px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    body { font-size: 18px; }
    section { padding: 60px 0; }
    
    .long-copy {
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 10%;
    }
}
 
 .case2 img { 
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  grid-gap: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Small phones to small tablets: from 481px to 767px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    body { font-size: 16px; }
    section { padding: 30px 0; }
 
 header {
 background-position: 700px;
}
  .main-nav {
       float: left;
       margin-top: 30px;
       margin-left: 25px;
    }
    
    .main-nav li {
        display: block;
    }
 
 .main-nav li a:link,
    .main-nav li a:visited {
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        padding: 10px 0;
        font-size: 100%;
    }
 
 .main-nav li a:hover{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFD700;
 }

 .showcase {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  margin-left: 25%;
}
    
 h1 { font-size: 180%; }
    h2 { font-size: 150%; }
    
 .all{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
 }
 
 .case2 img { 
 margin-top: 40%;
 margin-bottom: 20%;
 border-radius: 25px;
 width: 300px;
 grid-gap: 40px;
 width: 100%;
}

 /* Style the navbar */
#navbar {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

/* Navbar links */
#navbar a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>citrea</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <a id="logo3"></a>
 <header>
  <nav id="navbar"> 
   <a href="#logo3"><img src="img/Logo (mindre).png" class="logo" alt="citera_logo"></a>
   <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#produktet">produktet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#om_citrea">om citrea</a></li>
    <li><a href="#kontakt">kontakt</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <article class="hero-text-box">
   <h1>CITREA</h1>
   <h3>Vand med et shot af citron </h3>
   <a class="btn btn-full" href="#køb_her">Køb her</a>
   <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#læs_mere">Læs mere</a>
  </article>
 </header>
 <a id="læs_mere"></a>
 <a id="produktet"></a>
 <section class="box-me">
  <article class="top-box">
   <h2>Drik vand med CITREA</h2>
   <p class="long-copy">
    Vand er en nødvendighed i hverdagen, for at kunne opretholde din krops væskebalance. Da din krop mister mellem 2,5-3 liter vand om dagen. Og dette skal erstattes for at holde din krop sund. Vores hjerne består af 85% vand, og hvis den ikke er dehydreret kan der kommer negative effekter. Der samme med vores blod som består af 95% vand. Der skal vand med til og regulere blodtrykket. Dit hjerte består af 77% vand, som bruges til og reducere hjertesygdomme.Din nyre består af 73% vand, som bruges til og omdanne fedt til energi og dine lunger består af 80% som bruges til og optage ilt. // CITREA 
   </p>
  </article>
  <article class="container">
   <article class="box1">
    <i class="fas fa-tint fa-3x"></i>
    <h3>Vand er Essentielt</h3>
    <p>Det essentielt at skulle drikker 1,5-2 liter vand om dagen for at opretholde væskebalancen.</p>
   </article>
   <article class="box2">
    <i class="fas fa-lemon fa-3x"></i>
    <h3>Fordele ved citron</h3>
    <p>Der er mange fordele så som c-vitaminer, immunforsvaret og fordøjelse m.m ved citroner.</p>
   </article>
   <article class="box3">
    <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-3x"></i>
    <h3>100% organisk</h3>
    <p>Vi gør kun brug af 100% økologiske citroner, til at udarbejde smagene og skiverne i vanden.</p>
   </article>
   <article class="box4">
    <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i>
    <h3>Hvor kan det købes</h3>
    <p>Du kan finde os i din nærmeste supermarked, 7-eleven og tankstationer.</p>
   </article>
  </article>
 </section>
 <hr>
 <section class="collo">
  <article class="showcase">
   <img src="img/side baggrund.png" alt="Baggrund med flaske">
    <article class="showcase-left">
    </article>
   <article id="om_citrea" class="showcase-right">
    <h2>OM CITREA</h2>
    <p>
     Citrea er vand med et shot af citron saft i. Da vand er en essentielt ting i hverdagen og citroner kan gøre underværker, såsom forebygge forstoppelse, regulere blodtrykket, udskiller affaldsstoffer og styrke dit immunforsvar m.m. Der er mange fordele ved citroner. Så vi har taget det mest essentielle i din hverdag, sammen med et produkt der kan give tilskud der styrker din livsstil. Så drik din vand med CITREA.
    </p>
   </article>
  </article>
 </section>
 <hr>
 <a id="køb_her"></a>
  <article class="center_text"> 
  <h2>Køb her</h2>
  </article>
 <section class="container2">
  <article class=box5>
   <h3>7-Eleven</h3>
   <p>Du kan købe Citrea hos alle 7-Eleven butikker i hele landet</p>
   <img src="img/7-Eleven-Logo.png" class="logo2" alt="7-eleven logo">
  </article>
  <article class=box6>
   <h3>Fitness World</h3>
   <p>Du kan du vælge Citrea i dit All In abonnement i dag hos Fitness World</p>
   <img src="img/fitness-world-300x109.png" class="logo3" alt="fitness world logo">
  </article>
 </section>
 <hr>
 <article id="kontakt" class="all">
  <section class="find">
   <article class="case1">
    <h2>Kontakt & Find os</h2>
    <p>Adresse: Maglekildevej 7, Frederiksberg</p>
    <p>Email: Info@Citrea.dk </p>
    <p>Telefon: +45 40404040 </p>
    <p>Åbningstider: Mandag-fredag kl: 08-15. </p>
   </article>
   <article class="case2">
    <img src="img/maps.PNG" alt="Google maps">
   </article>
  </section>
 </article>
 <footer>
  <p>CITREA &copy;  KØBENHAVN, DANMARK 2018 
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Citrea-265740650959233/?modal=admin_todo_tour"><i id="facebook" class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a>
  </p>
 </footer>
 
 <!--Javascript-->
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
// Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp 
// Get the navbar
var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
// Get the offset position of the navbar
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;  
// Changes the background color when scrolling
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 if (scroll > 1) {
navbar.classList.add("sticky", "nav-color") 
  } else {
navbar.classList.remove("sticky", "nav-color");
  }
  })
})
   
 </script>
<!--javascript-->
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you would need to use js and animate the scrollTop (preventing the default action of the link) then you can calculate the offset of the div and add or subtract the height of the nav

Comment: I´m still a rookie. Can you elaborate or give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() - $('#navbar').outerHeight();
```

Instead of

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8v6s2bu/3/)

Comment: I have changed i to var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() - $('#navbar').outerHeight();, but it still doesn´t work. Do I have to define the outerHeight?

Comment: Yes, that´s it! There is just a weird bug with the first nav option called "produktet". The first time you click it, the position is off, but if you click it again it´s right. Any idea why?

Comment: "Køb her" and "læs mere" has the same problem. 2. time you click it works.

Comment: I've just fixed this jsfiddle check this https://jsfiddle.net/z8v6s2bu/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a click event to your nav links to handle the scrolling, taking into account the height of the navbar - please note I have also added a clearfix to your code so you can calculate the height of the navbar

```js
var $window = $(window),
  $navbar = $('#navbar');

// just changed this to use jquery
$window.scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $window.scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 1) {
    $navbar.addClass("sticky nav-color");
  } else {
    $navbar.removeClass("sticky nav-color");
  }
});

// this is what you want
$navbar.find('a') // get the links
  .on('click', function(e) { // bind click
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action of the link

    var $thisLink = $(this), // get the clicked link
      $targetElement = $($thisLink.attr('href')), // get the target element
      scrollPosition = $targetElement.offset().top - $navbar.outerHeight();  // calculate the new scroll position

    $('body,html').animate({    // animate the scroll
      scrollTop: scrollPosition + 'px'
    });
  });
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#Produktet {
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.4em;
  word-spacing: 0.8%;
  letter-spacing: 0.4%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.8em;
  word-spacing: 0.4%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3, 5%;
  letter-spacing: 0.4%;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
}

h2:after {
  display: block;
  height: 0.4%;
  background-color: #FFD700;
  content: " ";
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3%;
}

header {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("img/citera hjemmeside baggrund (mindre).png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.logo {
  height: 110px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.logo2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.logo3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.hero-text-box h3 {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.hero-text-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1140px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-text-box h1,
h3 {
  position: relative;
  animation: heading;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes heading {
  0% {
    top: -500px
  }
  100% {
    top: 15px
  }
}

.top-box h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.showcase {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(20%, 1fr));
}

.showcase img {
  width: 300%;
  height: 100%;
}

.showcase-left img {
  margin-top: 5%;
}

.showcase-right {
  margin-top: -5%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  margin-right: 15%;
}

.showcase-right p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.showcase-right h2 {
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-right: 10%
}

.showcase-right h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box-me {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  padding: 40px;
}


/* ----- BUTTONS ----- */

.btn:link,
.btn:visited,
input[type=submit] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1% 3%;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
  transition: background-color 0.2s, border 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}

.btn-full:link,
.btn-full:visited,
input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #FFD700;
  border: 1px solid #FFD700;
  color: #000000;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.btn-ghost:link,
.btn-ghost:visited {
  border: 1px solid #FFD700;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active,
input[type=submit]:hover,
input[type=submit]:active {
  background-color: #FFD700;
}

.btn-full:hover,
.btn-full:active {
  border: 1px solid #FFD700;
}

.btn-ghost:hover,
.btn-ghost:active {
  border: 1px solid #FFD700;
  color: #000;
}

.btn {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: btn;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes btn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* Main navi */

.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-nav {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  transition: background-color 200ms linear;
  padding-right: 4%;
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
  padding: 8px 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 90%;
}

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFD700;
}


/*__________________________*/

.long-copy {
  line-height: 145%;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 0.5%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  padding: 60px;
}

.container2 {
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  grid-gap: 6%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

.center_text {
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  padding-top: 3%;
}

.center_text h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fas {
  color: #FFD700;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
}

.case1 h2 {
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: -35%;
}

.case1 p {
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.find {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.case2 img {
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 400px;
}


/*FOOTER*/

footer {
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

#facebook {
  padding-left: 0.5%;
  color: #3B5998;
}


/*Sticky navbar*/


/* Page content */

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}


/* The sticky class is added to the navbar with JS when it reaches its scroll position */

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
}


/* Add some top padding to the page content to prevent sudden quick movement (as the navigation bar gets a new position at the top of the page (position:fixed and top:0) */

.sticky+.content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}


/* Sets the backgound color of the navbar */

.nav-color {
  background: #40717f;
  opacity: 0.9;
}


/* Big tablet to 1200px (widths smaller than the 1140px row) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .hero-text-box {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 4%;
  }
  .row {
    padding: 0 2%;
  }
}


/* Small tablet to big tablet: from 768px to 1023px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
  body {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  section {
    padding: 60px 0;
  }
  .long-copy {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}

.case2 img {
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  grid-gap: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Small phones to small tablets: from 481px to 767px */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  section {
    padding: 30px 0;
  }
  header {
    background-position: 700px;
  }
  .main-nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 25px;
  }
  .main-nav li {
    display: block;
  }
  .main-nav li a:link,
  .main-nav li a:visited {
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  .main-nav li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFD700;
  }
  .showcase {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
    margin-left: 25%;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 180%;
  }
  h2 {
    font-size: 150%;
  }
  .all {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  }
  .case2 img {
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-bottom: 20%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    grid-gap: 40px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  /* Style the navbar */
  #navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }
  /* Navbar links */
  #navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<a id="logo3"></a>
<header>
  <nav id="navbar" class="clearfix">
    <a href="#logo3"><img src="img/Logo (mindre).png" class="logo" alt="citera_logo"></a>
    <ul class="main-nav">
      <li><a href="#produktet">produktet</a></li>
      <li><a href="#om_citrea">om citrea</a></li>
      <li><a href="#kontakt">kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <article class="hero-text-box">
    <h1>CITREA</h1>
    <h3>Vand med et shot af citron </h3>
    <a class="btn btn-full" href="#køb_her">Køb her</a>
    <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#læs_mere">Læs mere</a>
  </article>
</header>
<a id="læs_mere"></a>
<a id="produktet"></a>
<section class="box-me">
  <article class="top-box">
    <h2>Drik vand med CITREA</h2>
    <p class="long-copy">
      Vand er en nødvendighed i hverdagen, for at kunne opretholde din krops væskebalance. Da din krop mister mellem 2,5-3 liter vand om dagen. Og dette skal erstattes for at holde din krop sund. Vores hjerne består af 85% vand, og hvis den ikke er dehydreret
      kan der kommer negative effekter. Der samme med vores blod som består af 95% vand. Der skal vand med til og regulere blodtrykket. Dit hjerte består af 77% vand, som bruges til og reducere hjertesygdomme.Din nyre består af 73% vand, som bruges til
      og omdanne fedt til energi og dine lunger består af 80% som bruges til og optage ilt. // CITREA
    </p>
  </article>
  <article class="container">
    <article class="box1">
      <i class="fas fa-tint fa-3x"></i>
      <h3>Vand er Essentielt</h3>
      <p>Det essentielt at skulle drikker 1,5-2 liter vand om dagen for at opretholde væskebalancen.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="box2">
      <i class="fas fa-lemon fa-3x"></i>
      <h3>Fordele ved citron</h3>
      <p>Der er mange fordele så som c-vitaminer, immunforsvaret og fordøjelse m.m ved citroner.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="box3">
      <i class="fas fa-utensils fa-3x"></i>
      <h3>100% organisk</h3>
      <p>Vi gør kun brug af 100% økologiske citroner, til at udarbejde smagene og skiverne i vanden.</p>
    </article>
    <article class="box4">
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i>
      <h3>Hvor kan det købes</h3>
      <p>Du kan finde os i din nærmeste supermarked, 7-eleven og tankstationer.</p>
    </article>
  </article>
</section>
<hr>
<section class="collo">
  <article class="showcase">
    <img src="img/side baggrund.png" alt="Baggrund med flaske">
    <article class="showcase-left">
    </article>
    <article id="om_citrea" class="showcase-right">
      <h2>OM CITREA</h2>
      <p>
        Citrea er vand med et shot af citron saft i. Da vand er en essentielt ting i hverdagen og citroner kan gøre underværker, såsom forebygge forstoppelse, regulere blodtrykket, udskiller affaldsstoffer og styrke dit immunforsvar m.m. Der er mange fordele
        ved citroner. Så vi har taget det mest essentielle i din hverdag, sammen med et produkt der kan give tilskud der styrker din livsstil. Så drik din vand med CITREA.
      </p>
    </article>
  </article>
</section>
<hr>
<a id="køb_her"></a>
<article class="center_text">
  <h2>Køb her</h2>
</article>
<section class="container2">
  <article class=box5>
    <h3>7-Eleven</h3>
    <p>Du kan købe Citrea hos alle 7-Eleven butikker i hele landet</p>
    <img src="img/7-Eleven-Logo.png" class="logo2" alt="7-eleven logo">
  </article>
  <article class=box6>
    <h3>Fitness World</h3>
    <p>Du kan du vælge Citrea i dit All In abonnement i dag hos Fitness World</p>
    <img src="img/fitness-world-300x109.png" class="logo3" alt="fitness world logo">
  </article>
</section>
<hr>
<article id="kontakt" class="all">
  <section class="find">
    <article class="case1">
      <h2>Kontakt & Find os</h2>
      <p>Adresse: Maglekildevej 7, Frederiksberg</p>
      <p>Email: Info@Citrea.dk </p>
      <p>Telefon: +45 40404040 </p>
      <p>Åbningstider: Mandag-fredag kl: 08-15. </p>
    </article>
    <article class="case2">
      <img src="img/maps.PNG" alt="Google maps">
    </article>
  </section>
</article>
<footer>
  <p>CITREA &copy; KØBENHAVN, DANMARK 2018
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Citrea-265740650959233/?modal=admin_todo_tour"><i id="facebook" class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-3x"></i></a>
  </p>
</footer>

<!--Javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp 
  // Get the navbar
  var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  // Get the offset position of the navbar
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
  // Changes the background color when scrolling
  $(document).ready(function() {})
</script>
<!--javascript-->
```

Comment: Yes, that´s it! There is just a weird bug with the first nav option called "produktet". The first time you click it, the position is off, but if you click it again it´s right.

Comment: "Køb her" and "læs mere" has the same problem. 2. time you click it works.

Comment: works fine in the snippet if you press full page - you must have something in your site breaking it - have you added the clearfix?

Comment: I forgot to add the clearfix class. And know the "produktet" nav option works, but not the buttons "køb her" and "læs mere". But tried @Shahjehan Ali Chughtai solution and that seams to work. But thanks for your time. Really appreciate it!!! :D